# Add G+ profile on G+ shares

Tags: social-media

Hi I've been trying all day to get my G+ profile onto posts shared from my webpage.

similiar to what forbes did here. http://www.forbes.com/sites/tjmccue/2014/08/29/google-authorship-killed-google-plus-next/

if you share their post on G+ underneath the share there is a link to their profile. [Seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5tGi.jpg)

Does anyone know how to code this into the page? i've been trying various methods all day, the g+ developer board is the most confusing thing i've worked with. Facebook, pinterest, twitter were all clear and simple. The G+ info is everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching around on the web i've found the answer to my own question. if anyone cares.

the tag shows up if you link your google+ business page to the site. not the google+ profile. this is what a rep at google told me, though its still not showing up, they said it will take up to a week for it to link.

hope this helps someone!